# hide voip notification ios swift

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications

Whats the correct approach for incoming calls on iOS. I use voip notification and e.g. when somebody is calling to me and I am not answering then after 30 sec I finish call and I send next voip notification (cancel notificaiton) to remove notification about call. The problem is that since iOS 13 we have to report all of voip notification. What should we do in this situation because I can't send voip notification (because I stop getting notification later due to apple politics) if somebody don't answer or when caller (outside of app) finish the call first then calle (app) have to get signal that call is terminated and to finish the call. How we should inform app that call is closed (if we answered or nope)? Maybe is there a way to report voip notification without opening callkit screen and terminating it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple of things that you can do here,

1/ I didn't understand why you are not able to use another VoIP to stop ringing, you should be able to do it. If there is already call kit presented in the system from your app you don't need to present another one, the system is smart enough to understand this and won't blacklist you. And in your case, since your phone is still ringing you should be able to send another VoIP without any problem, if this not working for you I suggest that, you should make sure you have an active call.

2/ You can create your own timeout mechanism, since app is awake and woke up with call kit OS won't terminate your app even if it is in background, so create your own GCD timeout or any other similar solution and use it.

3/ If you don't want to use VoIP at all, then you can use alert or background notifications however delivery is not guaranteed for these notifications, especially for background notifications.

Comment: 1. Im able to do it but when I don't report it then Im blacklisted. The second reason why im blacklisted can be - I answered for the call and caller (outside of the app) finish the call - then I also send voip to call CXEndCallAction to finish the call in app side. Its to ways when I get "remove" notification.                

2, 3. doesnt make sens, I have to inform the app when callee will terminate the call. Have to be a way to do it because e.g. messeger and whats app works

Comment: for 1. if there is already call kit reported from your app and if it is still active you need to report a new one, and your app won't be blacklisted. I am already using the same. For the 2 and 3 I didn't understand what you were trying to say, sorry.